# Tkz-berge sizes

Tags: tkz-berge

How to change width of all edges and sizes of all vertices. I can not do it smaller.

```
\documentclass[11pt,b5paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
    %\begin{scope}[xshift=7cm]
        \GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]
        \Vertex[x=1.93752,y=2.92474]{1}
        \Vertex[x=0.2184,y=2.36617]{2}
        \Vertex[x=0.2184,y=0.55858]{3}
        \Vertex[x=1.93752,y=0.]{4}
        \Vertex[x=3.,y=1.46237]{5}
        \Vertex[x=7.71912,y=5.92474]{6}
        \Vertex[x=6.,y=5.36617]{7}
        \Vertex[x=6.,y=3.55858]{8}
        \Vertex[x=7.71912,y=3.]{9}
        \Vertex[x=8.7816,y=4.46237]{10}
        \Vertex[x=13.5007,y=2.92474]{11}
        \Vertex[x=11.7816,y=2.36617]{12}
        \Vertex[x=11.7816,y=0.55858]{13}
        \Vertex[x=13.5007,y=0.]{14}
        \Vertex[x=14.5632,y=1.46237]{15}
        \Edge(1)(2)
        \Edge(2)(3)
        \Edge(3)(4)
        \Edge(4)(5)
        \Edge(1)(5)
        \Edge(11)(12)
        \Edge(12)(13)
        \Edge(13)(14)
        \Edge(14)(15)
        \Edge(11)(15)
        \Edge(1)(6)
        \Edge(2)(6)
        \Edge(3)(6)
        \Edge(4)(6)
        \Edge(5)(6)
        \Edge(6)(11)
        \Edge(6)(12)
        \Edge(6)(13)
        \Edge(6)(14)
        \Edge(6)(15)
        \Edge(1)(7)
        \Edge(2)(7)
        \Edge(3)(7)
        \Edge(4)(7)
        \Edge(5)(7)
        \Edge(7)(11)
        \Edge(7)(12)
        \Edge(7)(13)
        \Edge(7)(14)
        \Edge(7)(15)
        \Edge(1)(8)
        \Edge(2)(8)
        \Edge(3)(8)
        \Edge(4)(8)
        \Edge(5)(8)
        \Edge(8)(11)
        \Edge(8)(12)
        \Edge(8)(13)
        \Edge(8)(14)
        \Edge(8)(15)
        \Edge(1)(9)
        \Edge(2)(9)
        \Edge(3)(9)
        \Edge(4)(9)
        \Edge(5)(9)
        \Edge(9)(11)
        \Edge(9)(12)
        \Edge(9)(13)
        \Edge(9)(14)
        \Edge(9)(15)
        \Edge(1)(10)
        \Edge(2)(10)
        \Edge(3)(10)
        \Edge(4)(10)
        \Edge(5)(10)
        \Edge(10)(11)
        \Edge(10)(12)
        \Edge(10)(13)
        \Edge(10)(14)
        \Edge(10)(15)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code is not compilable. Could you please add your preamble, too? Your `\Vertex` and `\Edge` commands seems to be your own commands.

Comment: Please, edit your code so that it can be compiled. (Start with `\documentclass`, and add all `\usepackage` commands)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution.

```
\documentclass[11pt,b5paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
        %\begin{scope}[xshift=7cm]
        \GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]
        \tikzset{VertexStyle/.append style = {minimum size = 1pt, inner sep=0pt}}
        \SetUpEdge[lw  = 0.3pt]     
        \Vertex[x=1.93752,y=2.92474]{1}
        \Vertex[x=0.2184,y=2.36617]{2}
        \Vertex[x=0.2184,y=0.55858]{3}
        \Vertex[x=1.93752,y=0.]{4}
        \Vertex[x=3.,y=1.46237]{5}
        \Vertex[x=7.71912,y=5.92474]{6}
        \Vertex[x=6.,y=5.36617]{7}
        \Vertex[x=6.,y=3.55858]{8}
        \Vertex[x=7.71912,y=3.]{9}
        \Vertex[x=8.7816,y=4.46237]{10}
        \Vertex[x=13.5007,y=2.92474]{11}
        \Vertex[x=11.7816,y=2.36617]{12}
        \Vertex[x=11.7816,y=0.55858]{13}
        \Vertex[x=13.5007,y=0.]{14}
        \Vertex[x=14.5632,y=1.46237]{15}
        \Edge(1)(2)
        \Edge(2)(3)
        \Edge(3)(4)
        \Edge(4)(5)
        \Edge(1)(5)
        \Edge(11)(12)
        \Edge(12)(13)
        \Edge(13)(14)
        \Edge(14)(15)
        \Edge(11)(15)
        \Edge(1)(6)
        \Edge(2)(6)
        \Edge(3)(6)
        \Edge(4)(6)
        \Edge(5)(6)
        \Edge(6)(11)
        \Edge(6)(12)
        \Edge(6)(13)
        \Edge(6)(14)
        \Edge(6)(15)
        \Edge(1)(7)
        \Edge(2)(7)
        \Edge(3)(7)
        \Edge(4)(7)
        \Edge(5)(7)
        \Edge(7)(11)
        \Edge(7)(12)
        \Edge(7)(13)
        \Edge(7)(14)
        \Edge(7)(15)
        \Edge(1)(8)
        \Edge(2)(8)
        \Edge(3)(8)
        \Edge(4)(8)
        \Edge(5)(8)
        \Edge(8)(11)
        \Edge(8)(12)
        \Edge(8)(13)
        \Edge(8)(14)
        \Edge(8)(15)
        \Edge(1)(9)
        \Edge(2)(9)
        \Edge(3)(9)
        \Edge(4)(9)
        \Edge(5)(9)
        \Edge(9)(11)
        \Edge(9)(12)
        \Edge(9)(13)
        \Edge(9)(14)
        \Edge(9)(15)
        \Edge(1)(10)
        \Edge(2)(10)
        \Edge(3)(10)
        \Edge(4)(10)
        \Edge(5)(10)
        \Edge(10)(11)
        \Edge(10)(12)
        \Edge(10)(13)
        \Edge(10)(14)
        \Edge(10)(15)
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I try it.  It is too thick.

Comment: @ZYX Please give more precise comments. "It" means what exactly? Otherwise accept the answer

Comment: You can change the vertex size. I used 3 pt, but you can type e.g. 1 pt.

Comment: Now, I modified my solution. You can change also edge width with it. (The default is `lw=1pt`, I used `lw=0.3pt`)

Comment: You should also add `inner sep=0pt`, answer edited.

Comment: Do you know how to change size of labels?

Comment: In the options  of `tikzpicture` you should add `every label/.append style={font=\small}` after `scale=0.7`